# I'm implementing 'XOR' function and it fails for

Tags: python, numpy, typeerror, xor

```
import numpy as np

def AND(x1, x2):
    x = np.array(x1,x2)
    w = np.array(0.5,0.5)
    b = -0.7
    tmp = np.sum(w*x) + b 
    if tmp <= 0:
        return 0
    else:
        return 1

def NAND(x1, x2):
    x = np.array([x1, x2])
    w = np.array([-0.5, -0.5])
    b = 0.7
    tmp = np.sum(w*x) + b
    if tmp <= 0:
        return 0
    else:
        return 1

print(NAND(1,0))
print(NAND(1,1))

def OR(x1, x2):
    x = np.array([x1, x2])
    w = np.array([0.5, 0.5])
    b = -0.2
    tmp = np.sum(w*x) + b 
    if tmp <= 0:
        return 0
    else:
        return 1

print(OR(0,1))
print(OR(0,0))

def XOR(x1, x2):
    s1 = NAND(x1,x2)
    s2 = OR(x1,x2)
    y = AND(s1,s2)
    return y

print(XOR(0,1))
```

I completed AND, OR, NAND gate. and they all works really precisely as i expected. And finally i tried to make a XOR logic by combining NAND, OR, AND in sequence... But here comes the traceback error message i 've never expected like below. What should be modified to fulfill my original purpose.

TypeError: Cannot interpret '1' as a data type

Answer (score 0):

The first (and second) line of AND is not the same as the first line of OR and NAND.  That's the problem.  See it?

Ironic that you had unit tests for OR and NAND, but not for AND.

Comment: Yea you are right. Actually I've found it by myself during self-inspection.. That's why I've just come here just to eliminate my post because it was just silly fault... but as i see several dedicated comments here. This post should be remain here. Sorry for my awkward english.